# Maple not able to calculate Bernstein polynomial

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, computational-mathematics, maple

Hope you can help me on this one.

Please look at this simple Maple code: [image]

Obviously $B(1)=g(1)=4 \neq 0$. Why is Maple not able to compute this right? Am I doing something wrong?

Kind regards

PS: I'm using Maple 18.02.

Comment: sum(g(r/m)*binomial(m,r)*x^r*(1-x)^(m-r),r=0..m); subs(x=1,%); gives 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting bitten by the `(1-x)^(m-r)` term when `x=1` and `m=r`.

The `sum` and the `add` commands handle that differently. Your `m` is a fixed integer, and for finite summation you should be using the `add` command and not the `sum` command. The `sum` command is for symbolic summation.

```
m := 20:

sum( 0^(m-r), r=0..m );
                           0

add( 0^(m-r), r=0..m );
                           1

sum( 0^(m-r), r=m..m );
                           0

add( 0^(m-r), r=m..m );
                           1
```

The `sum` command is seeing `(1-x)^(m-r)` become `0^(m-r)` before `r` gets any numeric values. And so all it gets is just `0`. At the top-level, outside of any call to `sum` or anything, you can see this with the following command, where `r` does not yet have any assigned value.

```
0^(m-r);
                           0
```

So the expression which you are summing evaluates prematurely to identically zero, even before `sum` begins its work. The is sometimes called "premature evaluation".

Now let's try you example with `add` instead of `sum`. Note that the `add` command has so-called special evaluation rules, which means that it delays evaluation of the first argument until after the summation index gets actual numeric values. So it delays evaluating `(1-x)^(m-r)` until `r` gets numeric values. So it will now get exact `0^0` when `r=m` which becomes 1.

```
g := x->x^2+3*x:

m := 20:

B := x->add(g(r/m)*binomial(m,r)*x^r*(1-x)^(m-r),r=0..m):

B(1);
                           4
```

Another way to proceed is to perform the finite summation (using either `add` or `sum`) for a general unassigned name (`x` or `t` or `X` or whatever) as the first step. In this case the subexpression `(t-1)^(m-r)` will become `(t-1)^0` and produce just identically one (`1`) when `r=m=20`.

I'll use `m:=3` below, to make it show less terms. That doesn't affect the discussion.

```
restart:
g := x->x^2+3*x:
m := 3:

B := x->add(g(r/m)*binomial(m,r)*x^r*(1-x)^(m-r),r=0..m):

p := B(t);

          10          2   22  2              3
          -- t (1 - t)  + -- t  (1 - t) + 4 t 
          3               3                   

eval(p,t=1);
                           4
```

Note that `B(t)` for unassigned `t` produces an expression. I could have used unassigned `x` here as well, instead of `t`. But your example already was a bit convoluted because you were using `x` in different nested procs as the formal parameter name.

But look, if you are only ever going to use the operator (procedure) `B` by calling it just once to get an expression... then it'd be easier to understand by just using an expression in the first place. I don't understand why so may people create operators just to ever use them once like this.

```
restart:
g := x->x^2+3*x:
m := 3:

B := add(g(r/m)*binomial(m,r)*x^r*(1-x)^(m-r),r=0..m);

          10          2   22  2              3
          -- x (1 - x)  + -- x  (1 - x) + 4 x 
          3               3                   

eval(B, x=1);
                           4
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps for Maple: $$0^0\neq 1\text{ ?}$$

1. I was able to replicate the problem
2. It is odd but $\mathrm{subs}(x=1,B(x))=4$ in Maple.
3. Also $ Z\mathrm{ := unapply (B(x),x)}$ gives $Z(1)=4$.
4. Maple Primes is a better site for Maple questions